# Python compare 2 YAML files that use different keys/labels the represent the same "things" or values for comparison

Tags: python, key, unique

Imagine 2 different yaml files (or for demonstration purposes, 2 dictionaries)

```
a = {'A':'yes',
 'B': 2,
 'C': [-1,0,2],
 'D': {
     'E': True
}}

b = {'A':'yes',
 'G': 2,
 'C': [-1,0,1],
 'F': {
     'E': False
}}
```

Obviously they look very similar, but they have different keys for what intentionally appears to be similar values.

if we do a comparison of the two:

```
print(DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True, significant_digits=10, verbose_level=2).pretty())
```

we get this kind of expected result

```
Item root['G'] (2) added to dictionary.
Item root['F'] ({'E': False}) added to dictionary.
Item root['B'] (2) removed from dictionary.
Item root['D'] ({'E': True}) removed from dictionary.
Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
```

Since DeefDiff doesn't know that the keys represent the same "things".

It is possible to rename the keys:

```
b['D'] = b.pop('F')
b['B'] = b.pop('G')
```

and now the same DeepDiff call results in

```
Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
Value of root['D']['E'] changed from True to False.
```

So, is there an efficient way to create a "Translator" for `b` to `a` and automatically interpret those difference without manually writing over each key or creating a new dictionary for comparison.

We could create a "mapping dictionary" and iterate through them:

```
translator_b2a = {'D': 'F',
             'B': 'G'}

for key in translator:
    value = translator_b2a[key]
    b[key] = b.pop(value)
```

and get the same result... just wonder if there is a method/process more efficient or already designed.  This method will obviously break down with the yaml/dictionaries get more complex, such as when the level of the nested keys are different, i.e.

```
b = {'A':'yes',
 'G': 2,
 'C': [-1,0,1],
 'F': {
     'E': {'H':False}
}}
```

Comment: How about assigning `b`  the keys of `a`  prior to the DeepDiff? `b = dict(zip(list(a.keys()), b.values()))`

Comment: Oh nice! that works as long as the structures are fairly matched... I threw an extra example at the end of the post where that wouldn't work though, result : `{'A': 'yes', 'B': 2, 'C': [-1, 0, 1], 'D': {'E': {'H': False}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs there are actually several options.

**Option 1a:** concentrate on the value comparison, but not the structure

```
from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record 

aflat = nested_to_record(a, sep='')
bflat = nested_to_record(b, sep='')

bflat = dict(zip(list(aflat.keys()), bflat.values()))
print(DeepDiff(aflat, bflat, ignore_order=True, significant_digits=10, verbose_level=2).pretty())

###Output:
###Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
###Value of root['DE'] changed from True to False.
```

**Option 1b:** concentrate on the value comparison, but not the structure

```
import pandas as pd

def flatten(d):
    df = pd.json_normalize(d, sep='')
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')[0]

aflat = flatten(a)
bflat = flatten(b)

bflat = dict(zip(list(aflat.keys()), bflat.values()))
print(DeepDiff(aflat, bflat, ignore_order=True, significant_digits=10, verbose_level=2).pretty())

###Output:
###Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
###Value of root['DE'] changed from True to False.
```

**Option 2:** keep the structure of the first dict

```
import pandas as pd

def updateDict(init, values, count=0):
    items = {}
    for k,v in init.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            items[k] = updateDict(v, values, count, k)
        else:
            items[k] = values[count]
            count += 1
    return items

dfb = pd.json_normalize(b, sep='')
b = updateDict(a, dfb.values[0])
print(DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True, significant_digits=10, verbose_level=2).pretty())

###Output:
###Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
###Value of root['D']['E'] changed from True to False.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... this works for now, until I get more creative with finding ways to break it... I'm sure someone will make it better.  This handles the 2nd example where the nested Keys might not have a 1:1 relationship and also handles where there is an error in the translator (i.e. if the requested key is not in the "b" dictionary, it leaves it as it was... however, if the requested key is not in the "a" dictionary then you'll still have a "difference" show up in the deepdiff).

Don't really have to "enumerate" the first inner loop.  The `tupley` portion converts from a tuple back to dict format.

```
def translatorB2A():
  return [{'b':['F','E','H'], 'a':['D', 'E']},
             {'b':['G'], 'a':['B']}]

def convertB2A(b):
  translator = translatorB2A()
  bNew = copy.deepcopy(b)
  for translation in translator:
    skip = False
    value = bNew
    lastKey = ""
    for i, key in enumerate(translation['b']):
      if key in value.keys():
        lastKey = key
        value = value.pop(key)
      else:
        skip = True
        if lastKey:
          bNew[lastKey] = value
        break
    newObj = {}
    if not skip:
      for j, key in enumerate(reversed(translation['a'])):
        if j==0:
          newObj[key]=value
        else:
          tupley = newObj.popitem()
          newObj[key]= {tupley[0]:tupley[1]}
      bNew = bNew | newObj
  return bNew
```

Now you can run it on some dictionaries that represent YAMLs

```
a = {'A':'yes',
 'B': 2,
 'C': [-1,0,2],
 'D': {
     'E': True
}}

b = {'A':'yes',
 'G': 2,
 'C': [-1,0,1],
 'F': {
     'E': {'H':False}
}}

bNew = convertB2A(b)
print(bNew)
print(DeepDiff(a, bNew, ignore_order=True, significant_digits=10, verbose_level=2).pretty())
```

should get a result like:

```
{'A': 'yes', 'C': [-1, 0, 1], 'D': {'E': False}, 'B': 2}
Value of root['C'][2] changed from 2 to 1.
Value of root['D']['E'] changed from True to False.
```

Would be nice if there is a way to insert the changed keys in the same order they are in the "translated to" dictionary.  i.e. find a way to have b return as

```
{'A': 'yes', 'B': 2, 'C': [-1, 0, 1], 'D': {'E': False}}
```

so that it appears at a quick glance the same format as "a"

```
{'A': 'yes', 'B': 2, 'C': [-1, 0, 2], 'D': {'E': True}}
```